# $x\mapsto \mu(A\cap \bar{B}(x, r))$ is $\mu$-measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I have to show that the map $x\mapsto \mu(A\cap \bar{B}(x, r))$ is $\mu$-measurable for every $A\subset \ X$ and $r>0$, where $\mu$ is Radon measure. I managed to do this when $A$ is $\mu$-measurable set. How to generalize this for possibly non-measurable sets?

Comment: If $A$ is not measurable then the map is not well defined.

Comment: @drhab is there an easy way to see it?

Comment: Judging from the tag, this is a measure in geometric measure theory. There an object called a measure is usually an outer measure defined on the whole Power set and measureability is defined by Caratheodory's criterion. Therefore this map in this context is well defined.

Comment: I am not sure, if this works, but have you tried showing upper semicontinuity or lower semicontinuity for your map? Either would imply Borel-measurability.

Comment: @humanStampedist yes, I managed to show that the map is upper semicontinuous, but only when $A$ is measurable. now I would like generalize this to all sets

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that $\mu(A)<\infty$. Since $\mu$ is a Radon measure, you can find an $S\subset X$ Borel measurable such that for all Borel measurable sets $B\subset X$ we have
$$\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(S\cap B).$$
Then you can use your proof, by using $\tilde{A}:=A\cap B(0,R)$ instead of $A$ for $R$ big enough.

Let me show how to construct such an $S$. Since $\mu$ is Borel regular, you find an $S\subset X$ Borel measurable such that $\mu(S)=\mu(A)$ and $A\subset S$. Now let $B\subset X$ be an arbitrary Borel Set. Since $A\cap B\subset S\cap B$ and $B$ is measurable (and $\mu(S)<\infty$) we have
$$\mu(A\cap B)\leq\mu(S\cap B) = \mu(S)-\mu(S\setminus B).$$
Since $A\setminus B\subset S\setminus B$ we further conclude
$$\mu(A\cap B)\leq\mu(S\cap B) = \mu(S)-\mu(S\setminus B)\leq \mu(A) - \mu(A\setminus B) = \mu(A\cap B),$$
because $B$ is measurable.